# AG-Grid range selection disappears on next event handler

Tags: ag-grid

I am using Ag-Grid with react, and need selected range, its working fine only when accessing from attached onRangeSelectionChanged  handler, however its not available in api.getCellRange() when I call inside onCellEditingStopped when both are attached together.

i.e. is fine

```
<AgGridReact
  onRangeSelectionChanged={rangeSelectionChangedHandler}
/>
```

and below is also fine

```
<AgGridReact
  onCellEditingStopped={rangeSelectionChangedHandler}
/>
```

but when doing

```
<AgGridReact
  onRangeSelectionChanged={rangeSelectionChangedHandler}
  onCellEditingStarted={cellEditingStartedHandler}
  onCellEditingStopped={cellEditingStoppedHandler}
/>

const cellEditingStoppedHandler = ({api}) => {
  const range = api.getCellRanges()[0]; // undefined when attached with onRangeSelectionChanged 
}

const onRangeSelectionChanged = ({api}) => {
 const range = api.getCellRanges()[0];  // always returns value
}
```

What I am doing is allowing user to click on cell so they can start editing then drag mouse to select more cells, now range is selected at this point, I can get value in onRangeSelectionChanged event, and cursor is in one of the cell being edited, so now I an enter a value and then when user stop editing In onCellEditingStopped event I need value of RangeSelection, but its gone at this point even though visually I can see the cells are still highlighted then why I don't see its populated when invoking with api.getCellRanges() ?